# Compare selected Client with TOP N Clients excluding the selected Client based on Volume in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am new to Power BI. I have a requirement to compare selected client with TOP N clients based on volume excluding the selected client. The Client Slicer (dropdown slicer) is where the client is selected to compare with the Top N clients. For example, the image below:

[image]

If I selected Client E on my Client Slicer and comparing E with Top 3, then I want to achieve report below:
[image]

However, if I selected Client E to compare with Top 4, my result should look like

[image]

Note that since I selected E, it will be excluded from the Top N returns.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @parry2k at powerbi community, he has solved the problem and want to share the link. [Solution in PowerBI community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Compare-selected-Client-with-TOP-N-Clients-excluding-the/m-p/1673379#M667762)